# Flashlight Application With Timer

Tags: android

```
if(!isOn) {

              imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
              parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

              camera.setParameters(parameters);

              camera.startPreview();

              isOn = true;
              getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

 }
```

I wanna add a timer to the flashlight app such that it keeps the flashlight on for the selected time

Answer (score 1):

This is the code which works for me.

```
public void NotifyWithFlash(Context context){

    boolean ShouldIGlow = true;

    while(ShouldIGlow){
      flashON();
      try {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         ShouldIGlow = false;
         flashOFF();
     }
  }
}


 public void flashON(){
   Camera cam = Camera.open();     
   Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
   p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
   cam.setParameters(p);
   cam.startPreview();

 }

 public void flashOFF(){
  cam.stopPreview();
  cam.release(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanna add a timer to the flashlight app such that it keeps the flashlight on for the selected time so just set timer using Thread whatever you want as `Thread.sleep(user decided period);` for example `Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: thanks for your responce can you explain it please i m new to android development

Comment: Just paste the code in your if condition and it will sleep for 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Thread.sleep()` because it will block the UI. Instead you have `android.os.Handler` :

```
flashOn();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        flashOff();
    }
}, 5000); // 5000 ms = 5 sec
```

Comment: #Omar thanks for your rsponce can I use the values coming from textboxes instead of 5000?

Comment: yes of course ! you just need to convert the value to an integer : `String.valueOf(textbox.getText().toString())`